# Example of a ring with a unique two sided maximal ideal which is not a local ring (that is it has more than one left or right maximal ideals).

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a ring (possibly non-commutative).

**Definition** $R$ is called a local ring if it has a unique left(and equivalently right) maximal ideal.

**I am looking for an example of a ring (obviously non-commutative) which has a unique two-sided maximal ideal but is not local.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ring of $2×2$ matrices over reals is simple so it has one maximal two sided ideal, 0,  but it  has 2 maximal left (right) ideals.

Comment: +1 Note: “has two maximal right ideals” is true, but is quite an understatement: this ring has *infinitely many distinct maximal right ideals.*

Comment: The OP asked for two. There are uncountably many maximal right (left) ideals: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/maximal-left-ideals-and-idealizers-in-matrix-rings/8BD5401BE6283D5E04658C934AEEB328

Comment: I know they asked for “more than one”, and the note is certainly not to be interpreted as pointing out a fault, it’s just that some people are under the misapprehension that this ring has exactly two maximal right ideals.  The remark hedges against causing that confusion.

Comment: The text I linked to contains a description of all maximal left ideals of the ring of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Literally every [simple ring that isn’t a division ring](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&L=2), so for example every matrix ring over a division ring ($n>1$ of course), and the first Weyl algebra.

Beyond those also, every ring of linear transformations of an infinite dimensional vector space has a unique maximal two sided ideal, but isn’t local (and also isn’t simple).  In fact their two sided ideals are linearly ordered.

And if you have any maximal ideal $M$ of a ring $R$ that you know isn’t maximal as a right ideal, and it isn’t nilpotent, then you can force it to be a unique maximal ideal in the quotient ring $R/M^n$, which won’t be local because of right ideal correspondence.

Comment: "Literally every simple ring that isn’t a division ring" means "all of them" or "literally all of them"?

Comment: @JCAA Again, thanks for catching the omission, but I'm afraid I don't have time to play your games. If there's another correction you're suggesting you'll have to say it straight.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Is that straight enough?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit the insult out of your last comment.  For the sake of getting you off the topic of grammar and to your point, let's say that I think that in natural language "Literally every A that isn't a B" is the same sentence if "literally" is omitted.  Now your turn again: where's this going?

Comment: @JCAA Just noticed I forgot to tag you in the last comment. You were saying?