# Definition of local ring (unique maximal left/right ideals)

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, ideals, local-rings

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring#Definition_and_first_consequences) lists a few equivalent definitions of local rings, the first two of which are

> 1. $R$ has a unique maximal left ideal.
> 2. $R$ has a unique maximal right ideal.

However, it does not list this condition:

> 3. $R$ has a unique maximal two-sided ideal.

I feel that both conditions in Wikipedia imply $R\backslash R^\times$ is an additive subgroup, thus implies 3. Then why is 3 not listed? Is it because 3 is not strong enough in general? What is a counterexample? Or is it simply "too easy to be listed?"

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3761563/29335)

Comment: Every simple ring satisfies condition 3. Some of them have infinitely many maximal ideals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, condition 3 is much weaker.  For instance, if $R=M_n(k)$ for a field $k$, then $0$ is the unique maximal two-sided ideal, but one-sided maximal ideals in $R$ are not unique if $n>1$.